# C++ FLTK restting components

Tags: c++, fltk

I have a 5 choice components, for example

```
Fl_Choice* mySideChoice;
mySideChoice = new Fl_Choice(aX, aY, aWidth, aHeight, "Side");
```

This is part of a multi-step process.  At the end of process, I want to reset all the components so the user can do it again.  I'm having difficulty.  When the widgit is created, the text is blank, and the user needs to pick something for it to call the callback.  Its very obvious the user they need to click in there and select a value.

I was hoping to "reset it" with this code:

```
mySideChoice->hide();
mySideChoice->value(0);
```

Doesn't work, just picks the first value when I show the widgit again.

I tried this messy code just trying get somewhere:

```
Fl::delete_widget(mySideChoice);
Fl::do_widget_deletion();
Fl::check();
Fl::flush();
Sleep(1000); 
mySideChoice = new Fl_Choice(aX, aY, aWidth, aHeight, "Side");
Fl::check();
Fl::flush();
```

Doesnt work, even when totally recreating the widgit.  The widgit does not reappear on the window at all...

Help! Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ha!  so dumb

```
mySideChoice->value(-1);
```